# Есть ли ограничения для HTML внутри email?

Tags: html, css, email

В первый раз пробую письма отправлять с помощью JavaMail. отправляю HTML, всё окей, но пытаюсь подключить какие нибудь стили, а они не работают (открывал саму страницу шаблона в браузере - все ок). Вроде где-то на англоязычных форумах писали что есть некоторые ограничения на HTML, то что JS нет это вроде интуитивно понятно, а вот со стилями что? Доступны только инлайновые стили? Или это я где то неправильно подключаю что-то?

Ну и код, конечно:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Mail confirmation</title>
    <link href="https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" th:action="${link}">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success" value="Confirm"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Стили все прописываются inline прям в тегах. Использовать необходимо табличную верстку. 
Для примера можете выкачать шаблон http://tedgoas.github.io/Cerberus/ и повертеть будет намного нагляднее и понятнее.